# Choose border value for neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have for example simple neural network - one neuron and 2 variables.
For example we have binary AND action(0 AND 0 = 0 AND 1 = 1 AND 0 = 0, 1 AND 1 = 1). So we need to find such weights of w1*x + w2*y = T( or y = k*x + T, where k = -w1/w2) to neural network can work.
Graphically it look's like:
[image]

So as you can see T - is not any random value. If T = 0.5 there are no such w1 and w2 to make it work (you can't draw line y = kx + T to separate 1;1 from other points). 
To learn my neural network I use simple learning with teacher.

Comment: I think the idea that a neutral network is finding a line that separates the classes is somewhat figurative. That information is implicit in the learned weights; the neural network doesn't literally output a slope & intercept.

Comment: Yes, I understand that line is just a figurative graphical model, but it show what I mean: How can I choose border value? In some cases random border value lead to unsolvable system. Or I just need to use more neurones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an right common decision:
T must be random value and it's must to change in time of learning.
For example:

```
T += error*learningRate
```